# Commands to install Apache, Mysql and PHP through ssh

Tags: cloud-computing, lamp

I am not an advanced user. I have hired a machine in cloud and I am accessing it through Putty.

How do I install a LAMP stack on it ? I tried using LAMPP (XAMPP) from Apache friends but it dies saying it supports only 32 bit library.

Can someone give me a list of commands? (I need PHP with GD, CURL SSL support)

Comment: What flavor? `uname -a` (Redhat, CentOS, Fedora, OpenSuse, Ubuntu, etc)

Comment: First of all, this is entirely dependent on what OS you are using - "Linux" isn't enough info. Also, you shouldn't use pre-packaged LAMP/XAMP packages for production. They are packaged insecurely on purpose and are intended only for internal development and shouldn't be used on Internet-facing servers. You are better off installing and configuring each component by hand.

Comment: Its the latest Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others here have mentioned, we'd need to know your architecture, distro, and version in order to offer advice.

For example:

```
uname -a
Linux somebox 2.6.32-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 20 14:21:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 8 (Werewolf)

cat /etc/debian_version 
squeeze/sid

cat /etc/debian_version 
5.0.4

cat /etc/motd
...
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS

cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
```

Should get you close in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system? I'd recommend these [articles from Slicehost](http://articles.slicehost.com/) - if your distribution is listed under "Linux Distros" then they'll probably have something to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

After you discover which linux distribution you are running, search on [howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.org) site. There you can find a lot of detailed instructions.